Does anybody know of a top down map of andromeda in the style of existing (artistic) milky way maps?
I'm looking to make a digital model of the local group of galaxies and I can't find a good representation of the Andromeda galaxy from a top-down view.

how good is "good",  google find various "artistic interpretations" https://se-database.fandom.com/wiki/Andromeda_Galaxy?file=Andromeda.jpg

@JamesK that should work

Another option would be to use any of the AI image generators.

Andromeda galaxy is inclined at about 77 degrees to us (where 90 degrees would be edge on) which makes it hard to reconstruct how it would look from 0 degrees.  However there are various "artistic interpretations"

I found this one as part of the Space Engine planetary Database Wiki page of about the Andromeda galaxy.  It doesn't claim to be a "scientific" reconstruction, but it might suffice for your needs.

I don't see the bar or the 10-kpc ring, so I'd say "not very scientific"...

Previous answers are good. The thing is, Andromeda should be just very similar to the Milky Way is terms of its overall appearance so I guess you could use just whatever face-on representation of a late-type massive spiral galaxy you can find. Note that we have less info about the Milky Way's overall appearance than for Andromeda since we are inside of it. Maybe I would just get something from hydrodynamical cosmological galaxy-formation simulations like FIRE, Illustris, or EAGLE. Here are examples from FIRE and EAGLE simulations.


